# Unit test persistence layer - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I want to test persistence in Symfony2. I wonder whether it is better mock entities and provide to entity manager or whether it is better mock entity menager and pass entity to manager ?

I first option but entity manager throw exception than object is not entity doctrine.  How test persistence symfony  in PHPUNIT?

Answer (score 21):

Rather than writing **unit tests** you should write **integration tests** for the persistence layer.

There's a rule in unit testing "**Don't mock what you don't own**".

You don't own Doctrine classes nor interfaces, and you can never be sure that assumptions you made to the interfaces you mocked are true. Even if they're true at the time you write the test, you cannot be sure that Doctrine's behaviour didn't change over time.

Whenever you use 3rd party code you should write an integration test for whatever uses it. Integration test will actually call the database and make sure that doctrine works the way you think it works.

That's why it's good to **decouple** from 3rd party stuff.

In case of doctrine it's very easy. One of the things you could do is to introduce an interface for each of your repositories.

```php
interface ArticleRepository
{
    /**
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Article
     *
     * @throws ArticleNotFoundException
     */
    public function findById($id);
}
```

You can easily mock or stub such an interface:

```php
class MyServiceTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_Test_Case
{
    public function test_it_does_something()
    {
        $article = new Article();
        $repository = $this->prophesize(ArticleRepository::class);
        $repository->findById(13)->willReturn($article);

        $myService = new MyService($repository->reveal());
        $myService->doSomething();

        // ...
    }
}
```

The interface will be implemented with doctrine:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class DoctrineArticleRepository extends EntityRepository implement ArticleRepository
{
    public function findById($id)
    {
        // call doctrine here
    }
}
```

The implementation is what you're gonna write integration tests for. In your integration test for the repository you'll actually call the database:

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class ArticleTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    private $em;
    private $repository;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
        $this->repository = $this->em->getRepository(Article::class);
    }

    public function test_it_finds_an_article()
    {
         $this->createArticle(13);

         $article = $this->repository->findById(13);

         $this->assertInstanceOf(Article::class, $article);
         $this->assertSame(13, $article->getId());
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException ArticleNotFoundException
     */
    public function test_it_throws_an_exception_if_article_is_not_found()
    {
        $this->repository->findById(42);
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        $this->em->close();
    }

    private function createArticle($id)
    {
        $article = new Article($id);
        $this->em->persist($article);
        $this->em->flush();
        // clear is important, otherwise you might get objects stored by doctrine in memory
        $this->em->clear();
    }
}
```

Everywhere else, you'll use the interface which will be stubbed (or mocked). Everywhere else you won't hit the database. This makes your tests fast.

Entities in your stubs can be simply created or stubbed. Most of the time I create entity objects rather then mock them.

Comment: I would even go 1 step further and make my ArticleRepository wrap the Doctrine layer instead of extending the EntityRepository. Otherwise the instantiation of this class is still out of your control and classes needing them still depend on the EntityManager to access it

Comment: Wrapping is indeed an option. In many cases the better one, as this way you can inject other collaborators into your repository as well as the entity manager!

Comment: Would you use an in-memory SQLite driver or the same driver used in production?

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, but I don't want using intergration test. I want unit test, whether persist execute without errors but not save to DB and that's my problem. I want run test on production and I certainty that object work correct.

Comment: @M4ver Once you introduce the repository interface you can write a unit test! Just don't forget to write an integration test for the implementation of the interface. For everything else you write a unit test.

Comment: @noisebleed I use the same driver. Using a different driver is the same than mocking: you have no guarantee that Doctrine behaves exactly the same (plus this would force you to write any SQL query in a cross-platform way if you use SQL directly)

Comment: @noisebleed SQLite might not behave the same way as other DBs. In past I had issues with constraints being handled differently in SQLite compared to MySQL.

Comment: How do yo ensure that your unit tests are independent? Do you remove everything you persist?

Comment: @greg0ire unit tests don't persist anything. In integration tests the easiest thing to do is to drop the whole schema: https://gist.github.com/jakzal/a24467c2e57d835dcb65

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks Jakub, Christophe.

Comment: @greg0ire when using entities, which are unique by definition, make sure you generate a truly random ID.

Comment: @M4ver if you're hitting the DB, that's not a unit test. That's an integration test.

Comment: @noisebleed so that's one more reason to use uuids I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @JakubZalas  your code that's intergration test, test saving record to db. I want test whether code execute but test should not save record to db( don't hitting to DB). Test should check whether $this->em->persist($object) and $this->em->flush  not throw exception, that's it.