# Symfony 2.3 PHP unit test using mock objects

Tags: symfony, phpunit

Im new in Symfony and phpunit and im trying to do phpunit testing to the following codes.

```
/**
     * Creates a form to delete a Product entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('product_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }

/**
     * Finds and displays a Product entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="product_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Product entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
```

Can anyone help me

My Unit Testing code (just some part)

```
$mockFormBuilder = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
$mockFormBuilder->expects($this->any())
->method('setAction')
->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

And yes Im stock .. i dont know how to test setMethod, add and getForm to return a form where i can use createView Method again.

Comment: Don't mock what you don't own. In other words don't mock third party stuff (doctrine, forms etc). See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030745/unit-test-persistence-layer-symfony/35032687#35032687

Comment: So what should I mock ? if not the form builder

Comment: Nothing. You should write an integration test instead (and create the form instead of mocking it).

Comment: Oh. is Integration test still considered Unit testing ?

Comment: No. Unit tests are tests of "unit" (a class for example) made in isolation. You can only do it for your own code. For 3rd party code you should write an integration test, otherwise you'll never know if assumptions you made are correct. Key to write more unit tests, rather then integration tests, is decoupling (like I explained in the referenced post on an example of doctrine repositories).